# Netflix CDN web service says my client IP (a VPN) is a different IP in Fremont, California, not my actual IP in Singapore. Why could this be?

Tags: vpn, netflix

Context: I use Netflix via a paid VPN service. Some locations work for Netflix others do not.

I test my speed using fast.com, which directly uses Netflix' CDN. This shows low speeds with VPN connected of between 500kbit and 5mbit, and with VPN not connected, my full line speed of 50mbit. Looking at the 'details' section of fast.com after running the test, it shows 'Client   Fremont, US   65.19.150.235    Server(s) Open Connect, Netflix', which is odd, as my origin IP is in Indonesia, my VPN IP is in Singapore, where there are also Netflix servers.

I looked at the requests being made when visiting fast.com and read this blog https://netflixtechblog.com/building-fast-com-4857fe0f8adb

and determined that the JSON web service http://api.fast.com/netflix/speedtest/v2?https=false&token=YXNkZmFzZGxmbnNkYWZoYXNkZmhrYWxm&urlCount=5 is used to find which servers to use. The output from this service is:

"client":{"asn":"6939","isp":null,"location":{"country":"US","city":"Fremont"},"ip":"65.19.150.235"},"targets":

and then a bunch of URLs for Netflix servers in the California area (which makes sense, if Netflix thinks I am in California)

I ran a tracert to api.fast.com:

```
Tracing route to api.fast.com [92.249.36.200]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    34 ms    36 ms    42 ms  unn-89-187-163-207.cdn77.com [89.187.163.207]
  2   155 ms    43 ms    44 ms  unn-89-187-163-222.cdn77.com [89.187.163.222]
  3    43 ms    44 ms    48 ms  ae18.singapore2.sin.seabone.net [93.186.133.177]
  4   193 ms   257 ms   185 ms  hu0-7-0-0.franco72.fra.seabone.net [195.22.211.39]
  5     *      195 ms   194 ms  retn.franco72.fra.seabone.net [195.22.214.85]
  6   218 ms   293 ms   305 ms  ae0-3.RT.SRV.DRO.NL.retn.net [87.245.232.44]
  7   333 ms   407 ms   406 ms  GW-Serverius.retn.net [87.245.246.61]
  8   303 ms   318 ms   304 ms  185.8.179.38
  9   404 ms   306 ms   305 ms  5.178.67.31
 10   412 ms   316 ms   394 ms  172.16.75.2
 11   363 ms   356 ms   406 ms  92.249.36.200
```

which seems normal.

I also tried disconnecting from the VPN, clicking on the api.fast.com web service, copying the IP of the first CDN server, re-connecting to my Singapore VPN, then tracerting to that. This comes back as only 4 hops, and a few tens of ms, whereas there are many multi-hundred ms hops if connecting to the Californian CDN.

So the problem essentially is that the Netflix web service claims I am in California, and routes me via the California CDN, which is very slow for me as it goes Indonesia -> Singapore -> California.

Netflix does work, but with low bitrate.

So the question is, where could this 65.19.150.235 IP be coming from? It seems given that this returns consistently no matter which VPN address I use (from the same provider) that it might be something the VPN provider is doing. But I can't tell. The headers when I request http://api.fast.com/netflix/speedtest/v2?https=false&token=YXNkZmFzZGxmbnNkYWZoYXNkZmhrYWxm&urlCount=5 seem perfectly normal and there's no indication from tracert that the route to api.fast.com is going anywhere near California. Can anyone give an explanation that would make sense, given that without VPN connected, the 'client IP address' returned by their web service is my actual IP.

Comment: Which is your VPN and what is your IP when connecting to it? Have you checked that the IP is indeed in Singapore?

Comment: It is Surfshark. I have contacted them multiple times, but they have not answered if the '65.19.150.235' is theirs or whatever. My IP is indeed a Singapore IP e.g. the IP shown above in the tracert 89.187.163.207 (they have a few IPs, will vary). Regardless of the Surfshark server I use, it always returns '65.19.150.235' as Client from fast.com

Comment: Sidestepping the question a bit, but are you using the VPN to access a specific region's Netflix library or just to get around network filtering / blocking? If it's the latter, you can try Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 WARP+ which now has a desktop client, and get a reasonably close VPN endpoint (depending on your ISPs routing choices).

Answer (score 0):

The VPN IP is indeed in Singapore, which means that the VPN is working
correctly.
The problem must in this case be with the Open Connect network of Netflix,
so you should actually contact their Support.

With Open Connect, Netflix has taken the decision to not use the services
of large ISPs with massive data centers, but rather to build its own CDN
network using Internet Connection Points (IXPs).
These are smaller data centers, usually operated by third parties that
serve cities and municipalities instead of entire regions.
Netflix uses here physical appliances with up to 280 terabytes of storage,
so each IXP is far from containing all of Netflix.

This architecture was motivated by financial considerations, basically because
the large ISPs were too costly.

The way Netflix works is to choose the best IXP for you. If the video you asked
does not exist on your IXP, Netflix will choose another one that has it.
Netflix will also choose depending on the available bandwidth in the IXP
and its current work load, so as not to over-burden any one IXP.

Taking all these facts into account, means that Open Connect is choosing the
wrong IXP in your case. I cannot really guess the reason for it,
perhaps Singapore is over-burdened or doesn't have your videos, or perhaps this
is just an Open Connect bug.

All I can suggest is to contact SurfShark Support.
You could also try to choose another VPN server in another country that has
good enough bandwidth to Indonesia, in the hope of avoiding the problem.

References:

- [Building fast.com](https://netflixtechblog.com/building-fast-com-4857fe0f8adb?gi=c86bfd91cd6c)
- [Mapping Netflix: How the Netflix CDN Demonstrates the Importance of Content Delivery](https://www.aberdeen.com/techpro-essentials/how-the-netflix-cdn-demonstrates-the-importance-of-content-delivery/)
- [Managing Global CDN Operations at Netflix](https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/09/global-cdn-netflix/)
- [Is it possible to change the Netflix CDN?](https://www.reddit.com/r/netflix/comments/5h8dsk/is_it_possible_to_change_the_netflix_cdn_all/)

---

I have found the blog
[Tested: Surfshark with Netflix US & 13 Other Countries – Updated in 2020](https://www.wizcase.com/blog/how-to-watch-netflix-with-surfshark/),
where I found this interesting text:

> **Which Netflix Libraries Can Surfshark Access?**
>
> I contacted Surfshark’s customer support team and confirmed that the
> service can access 14 Netflix libraries.

From this I conclude that a VPN supplier needs a contract with Netflix
to get access to specific IXPs. At the time of the writing of that article,
SurfShark had a contract for 14 such IXPs.

I don't know the current state of relationship between Netflix and SurfShark,
but I think that your tests confirm that currently, no matter to which VPN
server you connect to, apparently SurfShark is obliged to access Netflix
via the USA.
One explanation is that today their contract with Netflix is limited
to only IXPs in the USA.

Admittedly, that's a lot of theory to base on only one blog article,
but it does explain what you are seeing.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it doesn't make sense. If I check my IP without VPN then it is 36.71.x.x. Ok. If I go to fast.com and check my bandwidth speed, and click more info then it shows 'Client IP 36.71.x.x', the exact same IP.  That IP is my personal IP, and if I  reconnect to the internet I'll get a different one. If Netflix decides that my IP is actually in London, and connects me to a London content server, then that would be Netflix's error and absolutely something to contact Netflix about.  However Netflix is not doing that - it's connecting me to Singapore & Hong Kong, which is logical

Comment: Now if I go to a very random VPN server - I chose Kazakhstan - my IP is 95.57.207.205. Ok. Now I go back to Fast.com, and client Ip is not '95.57.207.205', but '65.19.150.235' . Since the 'Client IP' given by fast.com is the specific IP address of my router at my home (or in the case of a VPN, my VPN IP address), then there is no explanation as to why that Client IP is appearing.

Comment: Noting that Netflix don't really want you to use a VPN, and many VPN services don't work with VPN, I'm wondering if this '65.19.150.235' is something that SurfShark have kind of wedged in, to get things to work. But I'm not really sure HOW SurfShark could do that, and maybe it is not possible for them to fool Netflix in this way, so if it is technically impossible to spoof the IP like this, it could be something Netflix have done.

Comment: I don't know how IPs are mapped to geolocations, but say, the UK Surfshark IPs (e.g., 185.134.23.54) and the Kazakh ones are in totally different ranges, so it doesn't seem like something Netflix could very easily 'rig' in this way, so I'm kinda leaning more towards this being something from Surfshark that their first-line support don't know about.

Comment: My explanation would be that the IP you are seeing belongs to the IXP and not to the VPN. The network structure of the internet is complex, and between Surfshark/Fast/Netflix the algorithms might mislead each other. You could try: (1) Another Surfshark VPN server in another country nearby, to see if the bandwidth is different, better or worse, or if another IXP is now chosen, (2) Another VPN service with server in India (free or trial, not Surfshark) to see if this changes anything.

Comment: I just tried Hola, and selected a French IP. Fast.com says I am in France and shows 'client IP' as the actual VPN  IP. I then changed the Hola country to Canada and it shows the actual Canadian VPN IP in fast.com. I tried also ProtonVPN, and connected to an Australian IP, and again it matches in Fast.com. I switched to ProtonVPN Argentina, and again the matching IP in Fast.com. So it seems like something SurfShark is somehow spoofing to Netflix.

Comment: Yes, SurfShark is somehow causing Fast to makes a mistake in this case, perhaps because of wrong geolocalization tables. Fast probably thinks that the IP range of SurfShark in Singapore is actually located in the USA, but for the other VPN providers that you tried its data is correct.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a mistake, or about geolocalization tables, because the client IP reported by fast.com when using any other VPN provider, or no VPN, is my actual (VPN) client IP. This is not a geolocalization issue. It's not about Singapore specifically, ALL of Surfshark's VPNs result in the same outcome, that Fast.com says my client IP is 65.19.150.235, even when the actual client IP is 205.x.x.x or whatever, and an IP in Kazakhstan, or Australia, or wherever else.

Comment: Geolocalization is just a theory of mine and I don't insist on it. From [this article](https://www.wizcase.com/blog/how-to-watch-netflix-with-surfshark/) I understand that a VPN supplier needs a contract with Netflix to get access to specific IXPs, and the article lists 14 such countries for SurfShark. However, I don't know the current state of relationship between Netflix and SurfShark. I can only remark that you have apparently found that SurfShark needs to access Netflix via the USA, so perhaps their contract with Netflix is more limited today than it was before. This is interesting.